# StreamBuilder not updating widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a Widget that has an AppBar with a progress bar, and a PageView with 4 pages, when moving between pages i am increasing / decreasing the progress bar.
I'm trying to do all the logic in my ViewModel.
This is my ViewModel (omitted non relevant stuff):

```
class RegisterViewModel extends BaseViewModel with RegisterViewModelInputs, RegisterViewModelOutputs {
  final StreamController _sexStreamController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  final StreamController _progressBarController = StreamController<double>.broadcast();
  final StreamController _currentIndexController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  final StreamController _isBackEnabled = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

  double _progress = 0.25;
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  setCurrentIndex(int index) {
    currentIndex.add(index);
  }

  @override
  increaseProgress() {
    if (_progress <= 1.0) {
      _progress += 0.25;
      progress.add(_progress);
    }
  }

  @override
  decreaseProgress() {
    if (_progress > 0) {
      _progress -= 0.25;
      progress.add(_progress);
    }
  }

  @override
  setIsBackEnabled(int index) {
    _isBackEnabled.add(index > 0 ? true : false);
  }

  @override
  nextPage() {
    if (_index < 4) {
      _index++;
      increaseProgress();
      setCurrentIndex(_index);
    }
  }

  @override
  previousPage() {
    if (_index > 0) {
      _index--;
      decreaseProgress();
      setCurrentIndex(_index);
    }
  }


  @override
  Sink get currentIndex => _currentIndexController.sink;

  @override
  Sink get progress => _progressBarController.sink;

  @override
  Sink get isBackEnabled => _isBackEnabled.sink;


  @override
  Stream<int> get outputCurrentIndex => _currentIndexController.stream.map((currentIndex) =>  currentIndex);

  @override
  Stream<double> get outputProgress => _progressBarController.stream.map((progress) => progress);

  @override
  Stream<bool> get outputIsBackEnabled => outputIsBackEnabled.map((isEnabled) => isEnabled);

}
```

And here is my View:

```
class RegisterView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterViewState createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
  final RegisterViewModel _viewModel = getIt<RegisterViewModel>();
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  final FixedExtentScrollController _weightScrollController = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 80);
  final FixedExtentScrollController _ageScrollController = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 13);
  final FixedExtentScrollController _heightScrollController = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 13);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _bind();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _viewModel.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _bind() {
    _viewModel.start();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _viewModel.outputCurrentIndex.listen((index) {
      _pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.ease);
    });

    List<Widget> pagesList = [
      SexPage(
        onConfirm: (sex) {
          _viewModel.setSex(sex);
          _viewModel.nextPage();
        },
      ),
      AgePage(
        scrollController: _ageScrollController,
      ),
      WeightPage(scrollController: _weightScrollController),
      HeightPage(scrollController: _heightScrollController),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorManager.backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: ColorManager.backgroundColor,
          statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: AppBarWidget(_pageController),
        elevation: AppSize.s0,
      ),
      body: PageView(
        reverse: true,
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [...pagesList],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController;
  final RegisterViewModel _viewModel = getIt<RegisterViewModel>();

  AppBarWidget(
    this.pageController, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _viewModel.outputCurrentIndex.listen((index) {
      pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.ease);
    });

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Text(
              AppStrings.skip,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
            ),
            onTap: () => _viewModel.nextPage(),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppPadding.p60),
            child: Transform(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
              child: StreamBuilder<double>(
                  stream: _viewModel.outputProgress,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Progresso(
                      progress: snapshot.data ?? 0,
                      progressStrokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
                      backgroundStrokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
                      progressColor: ColorManager.primary,
                      backgroundColor: ColorManager.progressBarBackgroundGrey,
                      progressStrokeWidth: 10.0,
                      backgroundStrokeWidth: 10.0,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: _viewModel.outputCurrentIndex,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: (snapshot.data ?? 0) > 0
                    ? InkWell(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.back,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              color: ColorManager.subtitleGrey,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () => _viewModel.previousPage(),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              );
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i'm calling `_viewModel.previousPage() &` _viewModel.previousPage()` from the AppBarWidget, the progress bar view is updated, and there is a scroll animation to the next page.
But for some reason if the onConfirm callback:

```
onConfirm: (sex) {
  _viewModel.setSex(sex);
  _viewModel.nextPage();
}
```

is called from within `SexPage`, the scroll animation is working, but the progress bar view and the isBackEnabled is not updating.
I have checked and a new value is being added to the `_progressBarController` sink, but for some reason the StreamBuilder does not receive it? same for the isBackEnabled stream..
What am i doing wrong?

And another question i have is where should I listen to the outputCurrentIndex stream, and call `_pageController.animateToPage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i had an issue with my Dependency Injection.
I'm using `get_it` and i used `registerFactory`, instead of `registerLazySingleton`.
Which probably made me have 2 separate ViewModels in each widget.